# Where is the memory leak in this Java scenario?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I am working with a Java application on a host that runs out of memory and causes the JVM to crash.

JVM is 8. For example, I set Xms and Xmx to 10240m on a 16gb host (running Linux). Over time, I monitor JVM heap (e.g. with JMX or a java agent) and usage stays consistent and within bounds. GC runs regularly and cleans up, and none of the memory spaces have an upwards trend over time.

But on the host OS, I monitor memory usage - through `ps` - `vsize` and `size` parameters stay consistent, but `pmem` increases over time (and I think `rss` too, but only just started monitoring it). pmem gets to 99% usage, and then jvm fails to allocate memory and exits. I suspect that `rss` is going to increase over time (it's already started moving that way).

Is this an indication of a memory leak in the Java application that the JVM is running? I'd assume the JVM itself is unlikely to have a memory leak. And the agent running at `-javaagent` is pretty widely used, so also don't think it is that. Would that be a good guess? If it is an app-based memory leak, what sort of stuff might leak, or what would be good ways of finding it? Something like JMX doesn't seem to be giving anything away, it looks like it's something allocated in memory that the JVM isn't aware of.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that you will have to debug this problem, there is no way to tell what's running on your server.

You can improve the situation by pre-allocating the JVM heap memory with `-Xms10240m` startup option. If `-Xms` is equal to `-Xmx` the JVM heap memory won't be resized.

Since you are on Java 8 you should check the [Metaspace memory](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace) utilization. By default there is no limit so potentially a faulty class loader can leak memory. You can set `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m` startup option.

Third possible culprit would be 3rd party library that uses off-heap memory e.g. some cache libraries access the memory directly outside of the JVM heap.

Comment: Thanks. I am setting Xmx and Xms to 10240m already. Metaspace is a great help, will look into that! Thank you. Failing that, will try figure out what is using off-heap memory.